# Conditional definition in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Assume you want to formalize the following definition in Isabelle:

```
add a b = 
 if f(a,b) ≠ 0 then add_1 a b
 if g(a,b) ≠ 0 then add_2 a b
```

where I do not want to give any *preference* to any option. In fact, the next properties I need to prove are:

1. add assigns at least one value for any input
2. add is well-defined

what should I use to model this definition in Isabelle? Perhaps a partial function?

You can see equation (17) and lemmas 4.3.4, 4.3.4 on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.05278.pdf) to see what lemmas I am talking about.

Comment: What value would you ascribe in the case of f(a,b) = 0?

Comment: @larsh I had I typo I meant g instead of f in the second case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `function` command with overlapping equations and preconditions:

```
function add :: "..." where
  "add a b = add_1 a b" if "f a b ≠ 0"
| "add a b = add_2 a b" if "g a b ≠ 0"
apply(atomize_elim) (* makes the exhaustiveness goal more readable *)
```

This gives you a proof obligations that the cases are really exhaustive and that the right hand sides denode the same when they overlap. Once you have shown this, you then must show termination (if your function is not recursive, then this is done trivially by

```
termination by lexicographic_order
```

If your equations are actually not exhaustive, then you first have to add more cases. In this example, you could add

```
| "add a b = undefined a b" if "f a b = 0 & g a b = 0"
```

which says that if both `f` and `g` are `0`, then `add a b` shall denote some unspecified value and this value may be different for every such choice of `a` and `b`.